# Rotation to direction vector

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

Ok, so I got a Three.js object. I can read the object's rotation, but I want a vec3 that points in the direction that the object is rotated, how do I get that ?

Comment: `Vector3.applyQuaternion(Object3D.quaternion)` doesn't do the trick?

Comment: Are you looking for [.getWorldDirection](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldDirection)?

Comment: both dont work. Vector3.applyQuaternion(Object3D.quaternion) just leaves the vector 0/0/0. getWorldDirection() gives weird values.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with a live example. As you can see with this one, `Vector3.getWorldDirection()` works as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/91whg4u8/

Comment: ok, wow. `Vector3.getWorldDirection()` is working, sorry, my bad. And thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

THREEJS uses quaternions instead of rotating around X, Y, Z in some order.
You can extract quaternion axis:

```
export function deconstructQuaternion(q: THREE.Quaternion) {    
if (q.w > 1) {
    q.normalize(); // if w > 1 acos and sqrt will produce errors, this cant happen if quaternion is normalised
}

const angle = 2 * Math.acos(q.w);
const s = Math.sqrt(1 - q.w * q.w); // assuming quaternion normalized then w is less than 1, so term always positive.
const axis = new THREE.Vector3();
if (s < 0.001) { // test to avoid divide by zero, s is always positive due to sqrt
    // if s close to zero then direction of axis not important
    axis.set(q.x, q.y, q.z); // if it is important that axis is normalized then replace with x=1; y=z=0;
} else {
    // normalize axis
    axis.set(q.x / s, q.y / s, q.z / s)
}

return {
    axis,
    angle
};
}
```